# Get image for captcha session in a flash webpage using java

Tags: java, http, captcha, flash

I want to get the current captcha that is displayed on [this website](https://formulariosgratuitos.dian.gov.co/WebDiligenciamiento/DefFormulariosGratuitos.faces)

I tried using the firebug, but I couldn't figure out how the page works because It runs on Adobe Flash.

What I want to do is interact with the page automatically, downloading the catcha's image, and let the user tip it from my program.

I had thought that It would works out using              HttpResponse, 
            HttpEntity, 
            HttpPost,
            HttpGet and
            BasicNameValuePair.

But first I have to find out the way to download the image from the catcha.

Comment: Since it's within the Flash movie, you can't get it the same way you would for a webpage. You'd have to find a library for dealing with flash movies or try some sort of screen capture.

Comment: Do you know a library that can help me or maybe an example for that kind of captcha?